# How to set CSS position properties to none ?

Tags: html, css

I have a multiselect dropdown in one of my kendo grid that i am using for kendo modal window.First place its dropdown box is coming good but because of alot of columns i have to scroll horizontal right, If I does that and click for dropdown to select the value is displaying same place where it was before scroll. current css class is set to position relative on parent.

How can i fix this issue ?

main.html

```
<div multiselect-dropdown-tree 
    class="geoPosition" 
    ng-model="this.dataItem.geoLocationsKeyList" 
    disable-children="true"  
    options="treeviewOptions">
</div>
```

main.css

```
.geoPosition {
    position:inherit !important;
}
```

Comment: How about setting it to unset?

Comment: 'None' is not a valid propety value. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position: static`. `static` is the default value of the `position` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `initial` as any property value, which will set it back to the user agent's default.